# in R Plot importance variables of Random Forest model

Tags: r, subscript, random-forest

What am I doing wrong here? What does "subscript out of bound" mean?

I got the below code (first block) excerpt form a Revolution R online seminar regarding datamining in R. I'm trying to incorporate this in a RF model I ran but can't get pass what I think is the ordering of variables. I just want to plot the importance of the variables.

I included a little more then needed below to give context. But really what I am erroring out is the third line of code. The second code block are the errors I am getting as applied to the data I am working with. Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# List the importance of the variables.
rn <- round(importance(model.rf), 2)
rn[order(rn[,3], decreasing=TRUE),]
##@# of 
# Plot variable importance
varImpPlot(model.rf, main="",col="dark blue")
title(main="Variable Importance Random Forest weather.csv",
            sub=paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S"), Sys.info()["user"])) 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My errors:

```
> rn[order(rn[,2], decreasing=TRUE),]
Error in order(rn[, 2], decreasing = TRUE) : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Subscript out of bounds generally means you've tried to use some value as a subscript in a matrix that is beyond the dimensions of the matrix. Like asking for the 3rd column of a 2 column matrix. But it's hard to see how anyone could help you more given how little information you've provided.

Comment: having trouble adding comments...

Comment: why can't I comment on Tim's below? i wanted to ask what he meant by "ran an example from the documentation online". How do I do that? Or perhaps he meant ran the Iris set from UCI?

Comment: Type ?randomForest and scroll down. Every help page has example code on it.

Comment: Right but I thought Tim was refering to an example file to use along w/ the exampl code.

Comment: Hi - daniel you won't be able to add comments everywhere yet as you haven't built up enough reputation. The only reason I ran the example was to see what the "importance" object might look like. The problem you were having can be identified just using `ncol(rn)` though - I assume it all makes sense now? :)

Comment: Have you also tried these two really greate resources? 1. Leo Breiman’s website (creator of RF): http://stat-www.berkeley.edu/users/breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#workings 2. try the example in the Liaw & Wiener paper in http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2002-3.pdf
of the Forensic Glass data set (A classification example):

Answer (score 6):

Think I understand the confusion. I bet you a 4-finger Kit Kat that if you type in `ncol(rn)` you'll see that rn has 2 columns, not 3 as you might expect. The first "column" you're seeing on the screen isn't really a column - it's just the **row names** for the object rn. Type `rownames(rn)` to confirm this. The final column of rn that you want to order by is therefore rn[,2] rather than rn[,3]. The "subscript out of bounds" message comes up because you've asked R to order by column 3, but rn doesn't have a column 3.

Here's my brief detective trail for anyone interested in what the "importance" object actually is... I installed library(randomForest) and then ran an example from the documentation online:

```
set.seed(4543)
data(mtcars)
mtcars.rf <- randomForest(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars, ntree=1000, 
             keep.forest=FALSE, importance=TRUE)
importance(mtcars.rf)
```

Turns out the "importance" object in this case looks like this (first few rows only to save space):

```
       %IncMSE IncNodePurity
cyl  17.058932     181.70840
disp 19.203139     242.86776
hp   17.708221     191.15919
...
```

Obviously ncol(importance(mtcars.rf)) is 2, and the row names are likely to be the thing leading to confusion :)